# How can i convert this string to normal string

Tags: php, string

I get text file content to array.

```
 $f = fopen ($file, "rt");
    $ln= 0;
    while ($line= fgets ($f)) {
        ++$ln;
        //printf ("%2d: ", $ln);
        if ($line===FALSE) print ("FALSE\n");
        else{
            $row = $line;
            $parts = explode("\t", $row);
        }
 }
```

But when i insert the value i got, it seen: \0M\0o\0n\0t\0g\0o\0m\0e\0r\0y\0 \0C\0o\0u\0n\0t\0y\0-\0 \0A\0L\0

Or : �3�1�8�0�0�0�

How can i convert it to normal string?

Thanks so much.

Comment: This looks like it is CSV data delimited by tabs and probably UTF encoded, if so you are going about it wrong. Can you pastebin or post a portion of the file?

Comment: This is a plain text file. 
100636 Community College of the Air Force Alabama US Service schools Semester 318000 100 S Turner Blvd Montgomery 36114-3011 www.au.af.mil/au/ccaf/ Montgomery County- AL 2000
100654 Alabama A & M University Alabama Southeast AL AR FL GA KY LA MS NC SC TN VA WV Semester 5095 4900 Meridian Street Normal 35762 www.aamu.edu/ Madison County- AL 510

Comment: Please click the `edit` link for your question and add it to the question so it retains it's formatting and delete above comment.

Comment: That looks like ordinary text. Can you show the code you use to display it?

Comment: You don't need to do `if ($line===FALSE)`. The `while` loop will stop when it reads that.

Comment: i get data, and use that data to insert into db. But it empty. My SQL seem:

INSERT INTO `bd_countryds` (`country_name`) VALUES ('\0M\0o\0n\0t\0g\0o\0m\0e\0r\0y\0 \0C\0o\0u\0n\0t\0y\0-\0 \0A\0L\0')